# How to fetch the actual request URL in Apache/PHP if it does not exist and user is redirected to 404 error page?

Tags: php, apache, url, httprequest

I want to fetch the actual URL of the request made by the client, how do I do that? I mean if someone requests a page that does not exists, like, `http://localhost/invalid.php`, and I have set 404 custom error file to `http://localhost/test.php`, then how do I get to know what was the actual URL requested by the user.

I have tried this in IIS7. I have set the Custom Error Page to /test.php, and whenever the user requests a URL which does not exist, I could still access that URL using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in /test.php and the URL in browsers still remains the same.

But I am having problem doing the same in Apache.  I have set the Custom Error Page to /test.php but when user requests a page which doesn't exist, the user is redirected to a /test.php and I cant access the actual URL which the user requested. I've tried this `print_r($_SERVER)` but did not find the actual request URL any where in the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+mod-rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do it by using a `RewriteCond` rather that an error 404.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?errpath=$1
```

The first line checks if the file actually exists.
The second routes the client to `test.php`.

Then in `test.php` you put something like:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['errpath'] == "" || $_GET['errpath'] == "/") {
        require("index.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "The url ".$_GET['errpath']." does not exist.";
    }
?>
```

That checks if `errpath` is nothing or just a forward slash (meaning the client would normally be showed `index.php`), and is so, requires it. Otherwise do whatever you want for the 404 error page.

P.S. Sorry if the explanations seem patronizing, I just hate it when people tell me to do something and I don't understand. I don't want to do that to anyone else.