# How does Facebook do it? Directories or 404 custom error?

Tags: php, facebook, apache, url, httpwebrequest

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522724/how-to-fetch-the-actual-request-url-in-apache-php-if-it-does-not-exist-and-user) before but got no answer.

Whenever we request an address like `http://facebook.com/Username`, the timeline of `username` is shown. I think that they have configured their 404 Custom error page in a way that they store the request path (in this case `/Username`) in a variable and then display the related data. Or have they created a directory with every username in their root directory? That means a billion sub-directories in their root directories?

I want to implement a similar functionality in my website, currently I am passing parameters in URL and accessing them using `$_GET`.

Comment: None of the above. __URL-Rewriting__ is the keyword you are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+mod-rewrite

Comment: I disagree on closing this.  It is definately a real question.  He specifically asked how facebook pulled off a feature.

Comment: @PeeHaa Will anyone please tell me what so 'unreal' in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common pattern on the web.  The term is called URL rewriting.  I've never done it in PHP, but I suspect this is done via the mod_rewrite module in Apache.

http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using URL rewriting in an .htaccess file.

The username is taken from the url and passed to a PHP (or similar) file to get data from a database which then redirects to the timeline page.